# Why is $-\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \log_2 \left(\frac{1}{N}\right) \frac{1}{N} = \log_2 (N)$?

Tags: summation, logarithms

$$-\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \log_2 \left(\frac{1}{N}\right) \frac{1}{N} = \log_2 (N)$$

In this equation, there is no index $i$ anymore. So, shouldn’t $\sum_{i = 1}^{N}$ turn into $N$? Thus, the equation should result in $-\log_2 \left(\frac{1}{N}\right)$, but it doesn’t. There seem to be specific rules for logarithms that I do not come up with at the moment.

Comment: So you are adding up $N$ equal terms, and dividing by $N$.  Each term is $-\log(1/N)$, and $\log (1/N)= -\log(N)$, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that it is $-\log_2(\frac{1}{N})$. However recall the identity
$$\log_b(x^r)=r\log_b(x).$$